# How make dynamic templateUrl in Angular

Tags: html, angular, templates, webpack

I have five variant my app and all of this have same functionality. But HTML templates are different.

Now i have five almost same *.ts files. For optimize, i have one of approach - make a logic to services, and after provide it to component, but i don't like it.

Can you help me solve this problem?

- I don't want make component dynamically
- I don't want use a lot of *ngIf in template (for each variant)

---

- I wanna 1 *.component.ts and 5 *.<%variant%>.component.html and 5 *.<%variant%>.component.scss 
  (and i will choose one of <%variant%> in environment or like UseClass with Services)
- I wanna  IDE (Webstorm) support - binding, link html variables with *.ts

---

Yes, I know what people ask this question before and Templates in Angular are compiled into JavaScript by the AOT, and this impossible. But maybe somebody solve it from custom plugin, webpack config or something else

Comment: I didn't understand your question, can you please explain it better

Comment: Fix description